# llamar a los que tengan mas datos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

buen dia, como puedo llamar de un array de un json los que contengan mas datos, estoy creando una grafica y debe contener los que tengan mas datos, tengo este codigo donde mando a llamar mis datos

```
vehiculoPorColores = () => {
const _this = this
fetch("/live/graph/color")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(datos => {
    const vehicleKey = Object.keys(datos)
    console.log(vehicleKey)
    _this.setState(
      {
        vehiculosC: vehicleKey.splice(0, 5).map((i, e) => ({
          name: vehicleKey[e],
          colores: datos[i]
        }))
      },
      () => {
        setTimeout(this.vehiculoPorColores, 1000)
      }
    )
  })
  }
```

para ser mas especifico:
[image: json]

tengo que mandar a llamar a los que tengan mas datos de esa lista, ahorita solo mando a llamar a solo 5 pero no son los que tienen mas datos, y necesito eso y que solo sean 5, aahh y trabajo en react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviamente primero necesitas ordenar tu arreglo para después tomar los 5 más grandes, puedes hacer algo así:

```
this.setState(
  {
    vehiculosC: datos.sort((a,b) => (Object.values(a)[0] < Object.values(b)[0])).splice(0, 5)
  }
```

`.sort` recibe el primer item de tu arreglo y el siguiente, como son objetos los items de tu arreglo puedes usar `Object.values(x)` para sacar el valor de tu objeto. `Object.values(x)` regresa un arreglo es por eso que se hace esto `Object.values(x)[0]`.  Entonces sacando el valor del primer objeto y el siguiente se hace la comparación y `.sort()` hace el ordenamiento.
Veo que mapeas tu arreglo para cambiar el nombre, también lo podrías hacer así:

```
const mapped = list.map((item, index, arr) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item);
  return {
    name: key[0],
    color: arr[index]
  }
}).splice(0, 5);
```